# plotting irregular time data from CSV with highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, highcharts

I apologize if this is a stupid question but I have no real experience with web developement and I couldn't find a good example to copy/paste from.

I am trying to produce a simple graph based on a CSV file, which looks like this  (unix timestamp, human readable date, T1, T2, T3) and which has irregular intervals

temperatures.dat

```
1454251326, Sun Jan 31 15:42:06 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.06 
1454251338, Sun Jan 31 15:42:18 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.06 
1454251351, Sun Jan 31 15:42:31 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.00 
1454251363, Sun Jan 31 15:42:43 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.00 
1454251376, Sun Jan 31 15:42:56 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.06 
1454251388, Sun Jan 31 15:43:08 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.00 
1454251401, Sun Jan 31 15:43:21 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.00 
1454251413, Sun Jan 31 15:43:33 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251426, Sun Jan 31 15:43:46 2016, 21.44, 21.38, 21.00 
1454251438, Sun Jan 31 15:43:58 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251451, Sun Jan 31 15:44:11 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251463, Sun Jan 31 15:44:23 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251476, Sun Jan 31 15:44:36 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251488, Sun Jan 31 15:44:48 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251501, Sun Jan 31 15:45:01 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251513, Sun Jan 31 15:45:13 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251526, Sun Jan 31 15:45:26 2016, 21.44, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251538, Sun Jan 31 15:45:38 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251551, Sun Jan 31 15:45:51 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251563, Sun Jan 31 15:46:03 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251575, Sun Jan 31 15:46:15 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 21.00 
1454251588, Sun Jan 31 15:46:28 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251600, Sun Jan 31 15:46:40 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251613, Sun Jan 31 15:46:53 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251625, Sun Jan 31 15:47:05 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251638, Sun Jan 31 15:47:18 2016, 21.38, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251650, Sun Jan 31 15:47:30 2016, 21.31, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251663, Sun Jan 31 15:47:43 2016, 21.31, 21.31, 20.94 
1454251675, Sun Jan 31 15:47:55 2016, 21.31, 21.25, 20.94 
1454251688, Sun Jan 31 15:48:08 2016, 21.31, 21.25, 20.94 
1454251700, Sun Jan 31 15:48:20 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251713, Sun Jan 31 15:48:33 2016, 21.31, 21.25, 20.88 
1454251725, Sun Jan 31 15:48:45 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.94 
1454251738, Sun Jan 31 15:48:58 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251750, Sun Jan 31 15:49:10 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251763, Sun Jan 31 15:49:23 2016, 21.31, 21.25, 20.88 
1454251775, Sun Jan 31 15:49:35 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251788, Sun Jan 31 15:49:48 2016, 21.31, 21.25, 20.88 
1454251800, Sun Jan 31 15:50:00 2016, 21.31, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251813, Sun Jan 31 15:50:13 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251825, Sun Jan 31 15:50:25 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251838, Sun Jan 31 15:50:38 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251850, Sun Jan 31 15:50:50 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251863, Sun Jan 31 15:51:03 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88 
1454251875, Sun Jan 31 15:51:15 2016, 21.25, 21.19, 20.88
```

temperatures.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
                      <html>
                      <head>
                      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var c = [];
        var t1 = [];
        var t2 = [];
        var t3 = [];
        var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'line',
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'temperature readings from Rasberry Pi'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: { text: 'Date Measurement' },
                    type: 'datetime',
                    series: [{ data: c}]
                },
                yAxis: { title: { text: 'Temperature (C)' }, ordinal: false },
                series: [{ data: t1, name : 'sensor A'}, { data: t2, name : 'sensor B'}, { data: t3, name : 'sensor C'}]
        };

        var jqxhr = $.get('temperatures.dat', function(data) {
            var lines = data.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                val1=parseFloat(items[2])
                val2=parseFloat(items[3])
                val3=parseFloat(items[4])
                if(!isNaN(val1) && !isNaN(val2) && !isNaN(val3)) {
                  c.push(parseInt(items[0]*1000));
                  t1.push(val1);
                  t2.push(val2);
                  t3.push(val3);
                }
            })
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

        });
    });
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

which generates the following plot

[image: Output of the above code[1]]

However as it, it just doesn't recognize the time stamps and just plots following line numbers, 0, 1, 2, ...

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to modify the code I would be very grateful!

( **update**

[image: after adding categories and new Date]

Comment: The reason of that is that your timestamps are in UNIX format not javascript. All of them should be multiplied by 1000, then dates will be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, based on another example I found I managed to construct this working code. The important point is to have data pairs (x,y) in each series, instead of separate x and y series.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Define and initialize "options"
    options = {
       chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x'
       },
       title: { text: 'temperature measurements' },
       xAxis: { type: 'datetime' },
       yAxis: { title: { text: 'Temperature (C)' } },
       series: []
    };

    // Read datafile
    $.get('temperatures.dat', function(data) {
        var series1 = { data: [], name: 'sensor A' };
        var series2 = { data: [], name: 'sensor B' };
        var series3 = { data: [], name: 'sensor C' };
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        // Slit each line into items separated by commas
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            // Add 3600 for timezone offset and multiply by 1000 to have time in ms
            t=(parseInt(items[0])+3600)*1000;
            val1=parseFloat(items[2]);
            val2=parseFloat(items[3]);
            val3=parseFloat(items[4]);
            // Add to series if conversion was successful
            if(!isNaN(val1)) series1.data.push([t, val1]);
            if(!isNaN(val2)) series2.data.push([t, val2]);
            if(!isNaN(val3)) series3.data.push([t, val3]);
        });

        // Push the completed series
        options.series.push(series1,series2,series3);
        // Create the plot
        new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
   <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```